# Locating a certain result on primes represented by a certain polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

In Theorem 2 of the paper "A polynomial divisor problem" by Friedlander and Iwaniec, Theorem 2 states that $$\sum_{a^6 + b^2\le x} \Lambda(a^6 + b^2)\sim cx^{2/3}$$ for some constant $c > 0$ (in the paper itself, they give a precise error term and make $c$ explicit).

They then say that "The proof of Theorem 2 will be given elsewhere." Where is this proof?

Comment: Where is the summand?  Gerhard "Otherwise We'll Call It Zero" Paseman, 2017.03.21.

Comment: I have fixed that error. Sorry.

Comment: Both the question and the answer should point out that the result is conditional on the existence of a Siegel zero (or, more precisely, on a small value of $L(1,\chi_d)$).  Hence, the title of their paper "The illusory sieve."  The result doesn't really exist, since the hypothesis is likely to be false!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They prove it in section 14 ("An Application") of their paper

- John Friedlander & Henryk Iwaniec, "The Illusory Sieve" (2005)

As pointed out by Lucia in the comments, the result is conditional on the existence of exceptional characters, an hypothesis which is generally not expected to hold.